# Javascript associate dynamic array

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON response as below;

```
"finalData" :
[
    {
        "message":"Display success msg",
        "status":["SUCCESS"]
    },
    {
        "message":"Display fail msg",
        "status":["FAIL"]
    }
]
```

Now this is dynamic. Meaning, I can either get just "SUCCESS" or just "FAILURE" or both
So finalData can be an array of 0 or 1 or 2 objects

My question is what is the best way to access the "message" property of the array dynamically. i.e. I want to know if finalData.message belongs to 
"status":["SUCCESS"] or "status":["FAILURE"]

So kind of associate the array

Comment: Are the SUCCESS and FAIL objects always returned in the same order? I mean if they are returned both, you get always the success first.

Comment: Can there be multiple values within `status` as well (it's an array after all)?! As a very naïve answer: `finalData[0].message` belongs to `finalData[0].status[0]`, so you'd figure it out that way...!?

Comment: `finalData.message` or `finalData[i].message`?

Comment: Little off topic, but just a recommendation, if the server code is yours as well it might be easier to handle this problem if you returned an object with the status as the key and the message as the value, e.g. `"finalData": { "SUCCESS": "Display success msg", "FAILURE": "Display fail msg" }`. Of course, this is assuming that you only ever have a status and a message, but if you need more data, make the values an object as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var d = { "finalData": [{ "message": "Display success msg", "status": ["SUCCESS"] }, { "message": "Display fail msg", "status": ["FAIL"] }] }

var status = 'SUCCESS';

var message = d.finalData.filter(e => e.status == status).map(e => e.message)[0];

document.write(message);
```

`ES5` code:

```js
var d = { "finalData": [{ "message": "Display success msg", "status": ["SUCCESS"] }, { "message": "Display fail msg", "status": ["FAIL"] }] }

var status = 'SUCCESS';

var message = d.finalData.filter(function(e) {
    return e.status == status;
}).map(function(e) {
    return e.message;
})[0];

document.write(message);
```

Comment: mmmm arrow functions

Comment: Thx..but could you pls update with ES5 code (non-arrow) ?

Comment: Just one more thing...what if I want to check if e.status is from within 'status' array...? should I do using indexOf ?

Comment: @testndtv Yes, if you want the status will be an array, you should use filter like this `status.indexOf(e.status) > -1 `

Comment: or i am thinking of using the jquery $.inArray > -1

Answer (score 0):

Check whether each code is there, then just use an if statement to continue conditionally, depending on the status.

```
var status = finalData[0].status;
var succeeded = status.indexOf('SUCCESS') >= 0;
var failed = status.indexOf('FAIL') >= 0;

if(succeeded && failed) {
  // code when both are true
}
else if(succeeded) {
  // code for only success
}
else if(failed) {
  // code for only failure
}
else {
  // code if neither are present
}
```